# How to combine two (or multiple) kinds of features as one final feature to build classification model?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, feature-extraction, feature-selection

Currently, I meeting such question:How to combine two (or multiple) kinds of features as one final feature to build classification model?

For example, I would like to do a classification model to predict the drug-target interaction, here for each drug I can get 500 features, and each targets I can get 800 features (this two kinds of features are independent each other). As a know, a simple method to combine this two kinds of features which just plus two together (that is 500 + 800 = 1300 feature for each drug-target pair).

Does anybody know other methods to do such kind of thing and use the combined feature to build classification models?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of methods which should work just fine even with this many features, such as SVM.

Also, there is a whole bunch of literature on this, including SVD, PCA, MDS, feature selection, feature transformation... you'll have to read up on these, we can't pick your magic bullet out of all that for you without having your data.

Comment: Thank you @Anony-Mousse. I understand some methods such as PCA, SVD a little. Another method such as kernel method used in the paper: "Protein-ligand interaction prediction: an improved chemogenomics approach". The kernel of drug-target pair `K = K_target kronecker K_drug`. then commen kernel-based method can be used to build models. But the compuational and memory-cost are huge, I would like to know, is there some aternatives to construct such kernel for drug-target pair or some methods to combine different domain features. Thank you.

Comment: How man records do you have? Kernel functions scale nicely themselves. Try a linear SVM.

Comment: For targets, I have 664 records, and for drugs, I have 445 records. So for computing `K_target kronecker K_drug`, it is K_664*664 kronecker K_445*445. the final matrix is too big to save to memory.

Answer (score 0):

Random Forest select the best features for your classification task using information gain. The classifier works for multiple feature sources and also types. For example, you can combine continuous attributes and discrete ones.

The training time is a little longer since you have to iterate all features multiple times but the memory performance and the classification speed is 
pretty good.